# Empty Space When Ionic App Pulled Up/Down

Tags: html, ios, css, ionic-framework, header

When I pull down on my app, I get white space at the top.

[image]

When I pull up on my app, I get white space at the bottom.

[image]

This happens when running on iPhone.
**How can I eliminate these spaces?**

Comment: Please check the position attribute  of div. I think its absolute, please change to relative.

Comment: hmm - doesn't seem to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have removed a setting some how. Add

```
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
```

to your config.xml

Comment: Thank you so much! Working now!

Comment: For me this solution was helpful: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-v3/issues/113#issuecomment-391996908